# In PHPUnit, how can I mock a function that is not part of a class?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

The project I'm currently working on contains a mixture of object-oriented and procedural PHP code. So I have something like this:

```
function doStuff($value)
{
    $x = $value + 1;

    return $x;
}

class MyClass
{
    private $field;

    public function setMyValue($amount)
    {
        $this->field = doStuff($amount) + doStuff(2 * $amount);
    }
}
```

There are a few of these dependencies, but there are few (you can count them using one hand). However, I need to write unit tests for the classes (using PHPUnit) and I have no idea how to mock the functions that come from the procedural side (in this case `doStuff`). From what I've seen, the mocking functionality in PHPUnit works only with classes.

I would just do it without any mock at all, but the problem is some of these functions do some IO operations; I don't think it's a very good idea not to mock them somehow.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Have a look at http://marcelog.github.io/articles/php_mock_global_functions_for_unit_tests_with_phpunit.html

Comment: Did you get a satisfactory answer from anyone to accept, or is there still issues with the suggestions?

Comment: @StevenScott Actually I decided not to write unit tests for that class anymore. Too much of a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call your functions (which are defined in the global namespace) from a namespace and always call them unqualified you can leverage [PHP's namespace fallback policy](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php).

> PHP will fall back to global functions […] if a namespaced function […] does not exist.

That allows you to create a mock by providing the function within the caller's namespace.

And to make your life particular easy, I packed this into the library [php-mock-phpunit](https://github.com/php-mock/php-mock-phpunit) which can be used together with PHPUnit:

```
namespace foo;

use phpmock\phpunit\PHPMock;

class BuiltinTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    use PHPMock;

    public function testTime()
    {
        $time = $this->getFunctionMock(__NAMESPACE__, "time");
        $time->expects($this->once())->willReturn(3);

        $this->assertEquals(3, time());
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like it, thank you. (sorry for the veeeery late comment :D )

Answer (score 1):

The only option I see is Dependency Injection, since your class wants to use a resource from outside of the class.  As such, this breaks some of the encapsulation rules.

How I have done this in the past, is to have these functions in their own class and require/include them, and when a testing variable is set, include a basic file with the same semi 'mocked' functions, which return known states.

My other way of doing this is to create a simple UTILITY class, that contains all these data functions, and then use dependency injections and mocks to do the testing.

```
class Utilities
{

    function doStuff($value)
    {
        $x = $value + 1;
        return $x;
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    private $UtilitiesObject;

    private $field;

    public function setMyValue($amount)
    {
//        $this->field = doStuff($amount) + doStuff(2 * $amount);
        $this->field = $this->UtilitiesObject->doStuff($amount) + $this->UtilitiesObject->doStuff(2 * $amount);
    }
}

    // Constructor Injection, pass the Utilities object here
    public function __construct($Utilities = NULL)
    {
        if(! is_null($Utilities) )
        {
            if($Utilities instanceof Utilities)
            {
                $this->SetUtilities($Utilities);
            }
        }
    }

    function SetUtilities(Utilities $Utilities)
    {
        $this->UtilitiesObject = $Utilities
    }

}
```

Test:

```
class UtilitiesTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    // Could also use dataProvider to send different returnValues, and then check with Asserts.
    public function testSetMyValue()
    {
        // Create a mock for the Utilities class,
        // only mock the doStuff() method.
        $MockUtilities = $this->getMock('Utilities', array('doStuff'));

        // Set up the expectation for the doStuff() method 
        $MockUtilities->expects($this->any())
                    ->method('doStuff')
                    ->will($this->returnValue(1));

        // Create Test Object - Pass our Mock as the Utilities
        $TestClass = new MyClass($MockUtilities);
        // Or
        // $TestClass = new MyClass();
        // $TestClass->SetUtilitiess($MockUtilities);

        // Test doStuff
        $amount = 10;   // Could be checked with the Mock functions
        $this->assertEquals(2, $TestClass->doStuff($amount));       // Mock always returns 1, so 1+1=2
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but the only problem is that you still will have a hard time trying to test that utility class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to redefine "mock" these functions.

One option to use PHP Library  - [Patchwork](https://github.com/antecedent/patchwork)

```
Patchwork\replace("size", function($x)
{
 return "huge";
});
```

Or hardcode solution - runkit extension (installed through PECL) -

[Runkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php)

```
bool runkit_function_redefine ( string $funcname , string $arglist , string $code )
```